# Is the formula (∃x)(∀y)ϕ(x, y) provable or refutable from T?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, model-theory

Is the formula (∃x)(∀y)ϕ(x, y) provable or refutable from T?

```
T = {(∀x)¬E(x, x), (∀x)(∀y)(E(x, y) → E(y, x)), (∀x)(∃y)ϕ(x, y)}
```

E(x,y) means that x and y are neighbors.
I think is provable because (∀x)(∀y)(E(x, y) → E(y, x) in this statement they are implying.

I believe ϕ(x, y) is same as E(x,y)

This is from first part of question

(That is, E(x, y)
means in a graph that “the vertices x and y are adjacent”.) Write a formula ϕ(x, y) in
the first-order logic over the language
(The phrases “x and y
are adjacent” and “x and y are neighbors” have the same meaning.)

Comment: Without knowing what T represents, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: hi Nomi. just to second @LeeMosher's comment, I think they meant to write that we need to know what $\phi$ represents to answer the question.

Comment: i have edited it. @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: @Nomi as a side note – it is extremely peculiar that the problem would use $E(x,y)$ and $\phi(x,y)$ to mean the same thing! are you sure you're understanding correctly? to remove confusion I would recommend further replacing every instance of $\phi(x,y)$ with $E(x,y)$ in the question, as the instances of $\phi$ are completely redundant

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom https://imgur.com/a/8PZdJQM here is full question. I cant make sense out of it if its not same. What do you think?

Comment: hi Nomi, that is in fact a very different question! :) they write: "write a formula $\phi(x,y)$ ... expressing that $x$ and $y$ have exactly two common neighbors". this is **not** the same as asking for $\phi(x,y)$ to express that $x$ and $y$ *are* neighbors

Comment: instead the sentence $\phi(x,y)$ should say the following: "there exist exactly two elements $z$ such that $E(x,z)$ and $E(y,z)$ both hold". does the difference make sense to you? (and can you see how to do that?)

Comment: since GEdgar has already answered your question as you wrote it, I would recommend asking a different question that addresses the problem as your textbook wrote it :)

Comment: I have made a new post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\phi$ is the same as $E$.
Note $(\exists x)(\forall y) E(x,y)$ implies $(\exists x)E(x,x)$; but this
contradicts $(\forall x)\neg E(x,x)$.  So $T$ refutes $(\exists x)(\forall y) E(x,y)$.

Comment: +1, this answer is of course much better than mine! but there's one detail which (imo) should be pointed out to the OP: for this proof to work you need to first check that $T$ is consistent.

Comment: Good point.  If $T$ is inconsistent, then any statement is both proved and refuted by $T$.

Comment: BUT NOTE:  The full statement shows that $\phi$ is not the same as $E$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451207/